# Test Timeout ignored in nunit3

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have test like this. It's more functional test than unit test. The test are doing some rest request.

When test is running for long time, it is not canceled when timeout value pass but it is cancelled later(40 seconds instead of 1).

Same issue is happening when I use nunit3-console to run tests directly with `--timeout=1000` param.

What is causing this issue? Can be done something about it?

```
[Test, Timeout(1000)]
[TestCase(TestEnvironments.PreIntegration, Category = TestConfigurationConstants.PREINTEGRATION)]
[TestCase(TestEnvironments.Integration, Category = TestConfigurationConstants.INTEGRATION)]
public void CreateAccount(TestEnvironments environment)
{
    var testCase = testEnvironments[environment];

    var userCredentials = new UserCredentials(settings.Default.AdminName, settings.Default.AdminPassword);

    SetProtocol(testCase);
    var adminToken = RestCommand.GetUserAccess(testCase.Keycloak, userCredentials).AccessToken;

    CleanExistingTestUsers(testCase, adminToken);

    var userResponse = RestCommand.CreateUser(testCase.Host, adminToken, configTests.GetTestUser(Name),
            settings.Default.TestPassword);
    Assert.AreEqual("0", userResponse.Error);

    RestCommand.DeleteUser(testCase.Host, adminToken, userResponse.Id);
 }
```

Comment: Please note that [Timeout is not currently available in the .NET Standard builds of the framework](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Timeout-Attribute). Have you tried with [MaxTime](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/MaxTime-Attribute)?

Comment: oh, i see. thank you :), I have tried MaxTime but its not shuting down test, when they takes to long

Comment: Yes, that's the disadvantage of MaxTime - it still waits for the test to finish.

Comment: Oh and one more thing - this is probably not your problem, but `Starting with NUnit version 2.5.5, the Timeout attribute is ignored when the tests are executed in a debugger` - source: [NUnit Timed Tests](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NUnitTimedTests.aspx)

Comment: One other suggestion: this probably isn't it; but you can't tell from the code that is in the question... Check that the `TimeoutAttribute` you're using is the one from the NUnit namespace, not from somewhere else.